# copying the texlive 2019 setup from virtual machine to real hardware on windows 10

Tags: miktex, texlive, installing, texlive-2019

I had installed texlive in a vmware virtual machine on Windows 10 (the virtual machine OS is Windows 10)
I thought of using it on a real physical machine. 
On that real physical machine I copied the folder from vmware virtual machine texlive from `C:\texlive`
to real physical machine  I have copied all the 6 Gb content to real physical machine in

`C:\installation\texlive`
directory.
I want to know what should I do to make it work?
I already have miktex installation on this physical machine.
The folder moved/copied is texlive 2019.

Answer (score 1):

- Your TeXLive would more or less work as-is if you just add `c:\texlive\2019\bin\win32` to the searchpath, although you would miss out on other system integration such as file associations.
- Or, if you run `c:\texlive\bin\win32\tlaunch`, it will turn your copy into a launcher-based installation, see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tlaunch. Afterwards, you can convert between 'classic' and launcher mode with the tlaunchmode script.
- Or, if you click on `c:\texlive\2019\tl-tray-menu`, then you get a tray menu from which you can perform various TeXLive-related tasks. This is maybe the best solution, since it will not interfere with your  MiKTeX.